# routing problem in asp.net mvc 3.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When I try sample application which is made as default with asp.net mvc 3.0, the home and about links just work fine. But whenever I try to add custom route data in global.asax like 
controller/action/id=urlhelper.optional,param=urlhelper.optional and run the project, all the links' href just vanishes.
ie. `<a href="">Home</a>` like markup gets generated. Please help.
Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in MVC 3. Here is a blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx